# Is there a sunnah prayer before salat aljumua (Friday prayer)?

Tags: salat, sunnah, jumuah

After the first *adhan* for *salat al-jumu'a*, but before the imam comes, I see many people praying two *rakat*.  Then after the congregational *salah* is finished, they prayer another two *rakat*.

I know that the imam prays four *rakat* before he comes to the minbar, but what about for everyone else?  Is there a sunnah prayer between the *adhan* and the *salat al-jumu'ah*?

Comment: Best thing is to ask them

Comment: And one of them who do it is me..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of the Prophet there was one adan before Imam comes to Menbar

> The person who increased the number of Adhans for the Jumua prayers to
> three was `Uthman bin` Affan and it was when the number of the
> (Muslim) people of Medina had increased. In the lifetime of the
> Prophet there was only one Mu'adh-dhin and the Adhan used to be
> pronounced only after the Imam had taken his seat (i.e. on the
> pulpit).
>
> حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو نُعَيْمٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الْعَزِيزِ بْنُ
> أَبِي سَلَمَةَ الْمَاجِشُونُ، عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، عَنِ السَّائِبِ بْنِ
> يَزِيدَ، أَنَّ الَّذِي، زَادَ التَّأْذِينَ الثَّالِثَ يَوْمَ
> الْجُمُعَةِ عُثْمَانُ بْنُ عَفَّانَ ـ رضى الله عنه ـ حِينَ كَثُرَ
> أَهْلُ الْمَدِينَةِ، وَلَمْ يَكُنْ لِلنَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم
> مُؤَذِّنٌ غَيْرَ وَاحِدٍ، وَكَانَ التَّأْذِينُ يَوْمَ الْجُمُعَةِ
> حِينَ يَجْلِسُ الإِمَامُ، يَعْنِي عَلَى الْمِنْبَرِ‏.‏

Sahih Al-Bukhari

But here nafel absolute mean it not sunnah ratimbeh

> The Prophet (p.b.u.h) said, "Whoever takes a bath on Friday, purifies
> himself as much as he can, then uses his (hair) oil or perfumes
> himself with the scent of his house, then proceeds (for the Jumua
> prayer) and does not separate two persons sitting together (in the
> mosque), then prays as much as (Allah has) written for him and then
> remains silent while the Imam is delivering the Khutba, his sins
> in-between the present and the last Friday would be forgiven."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا آدَمُ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ أَبِي ذِئْبٍ، عَنْ سَعِيدٍ
> الْمَقْبُرِيِّ، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي أَبِي، عَنِ ابْنِ وَدِيعَةَ، عَنْ
> سَلْمَانَ الْفَارِسِيِّ، قَالَ قَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏
> "‏ لاَ يَغْتَسِلُ رَجُلٌ يَوْمَ الْجُمُعَةِ، وَيَتَطَهَّرُ مَا
> اسْتَطَاعَ مِنْ طُهْرٍ، وَيَدَّهِنُ مِنْ دُهْنِهِ، أَوْ يَمَسُّ مِنْ
> طِيبِ بَيْتِهِ ثُمَّ يَخْرُجُ، فَلاَ يُفَرِّقُ بَيْنَ اثْنَيْنِ، ثُمَّ
> يُصَلِّي مَا كُتِبَ لَهُ، ثُمَّ يُنْصِتُ إِذَا تَكَلَّمَ الإِمَامُ،
> إِلاَّ غُفِرَ لَهُ مَا بَيْنَهُ وَبَيْنَ الْجُمُعَةِ الأُخْرَى ‏"‏‏.

Sahih Al-Bukhari

And in Fateh Albary said: it's not proved by anything

> " وأما سنة الجمعة التي قبلها فلم يثبت فيها شيء " انتهى.
>
> "فتح الباري" (2/410).

Comment: good to know all this but where is the 1 & 2 para from?

Comment: also there is nothing like 2:426

Comment: The 1 & 2 from Sahih al-Bukhari and the third from Fateh Albary

Comment: @Ashu: There is, but the quote is not from it, it's from 2:410

Comment: A decent answer, but you need to cite your proofs in your answer. More proofs are needed here.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get the conclusion. Is it not a sunnah?

Comment: Yes it's not a sunnah, but you can prayer it, check this http://islamqa.info/ar/ref/117689, but it's in Arabic.