# How many Sunnat rakats are there in Jumma prayer?

Tags: salat, jumuah

Assalamualaikum, as the question says, how many Sunnat rakats do I need to perform before or after Jumma prayer(friday).

Comment: well the word sunnah implies that it isn't obligated you don't *need* to perform them the real question is how many sunnah rak3at *may* you pray

Comment: @NesreenA Assalamualaikum. See the answers below to clear your concept about Sunnat first (and don't provide such answers firsthand)

Comment: Closely related [Is there a sunnah prayer before salat aljumua (Friday prayer)?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/is-there-a-sunnah-prayer-before-salat-aljumua-friday-prayer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 4 Sunnah(moaqda), 2 Farz(compulsory) ,4 Sunnah(gher-moaqda), 2 Sunnah(moaqda), 2 Nafal.
That is the correct order aswell, So in total there are 14 rakaat in jumm'a salaah  .

Farz is compulsory, what you perform with the Imaam!

Comment: yes but there are also 4 sunnah which are not compulsory, see more here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/is-there-a-sunnah-prayer-before-salat-aljumua-friday-prayer

Comment: Do you have an evidence for that? All I know is that the sahaba came as early as possible to the mosque and just kept praying sets of 2 rak'as until the call of prayer was made when the Prophet came out and after the prayer there are either 2 raka'a at the msoque and 2 at home or 4 at home which are recommended.

Comment: Is there any clarification for this ? There is a lot of confusion regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Walikum 'Assalam,

You need to separate what's considered Friday prayer with what's considered something else.

Friday prayer is kutba + 2 rakat

Now there are sunnah prayers associated with the Friday prayer and those are the same as dhuhur.

Before the prayer = 2 or 4 rakat (depends which school you follow, for shafi'is the sunnah is fulfilled by doing 2, for hanafis the sunnah is fulfilled by doing 4)4)

After the prayer = 2 rakat

So these are all the prayers that are associated with the Friday prayer.

Additionally, there's a sunnah prayer called "salutation of the mosque", which are the 2 rakat you perform when you enter a mosque.
Since people go to the mosque for Friday prayers, they usually do this sunnah as well.