# From the the Sunni Hanafi perspective, can the nafl prayers before Jumu'ah prayers be prayed after Jumu'ah prayers instead?

Tags: salat, sunni, hanafi, jumuah

Is praying two Fard Jumu'ah behind the imam enough? I usually pray 2 sunnah tahiyatul masjid, 4 sunnah kabla-l jumuah, 2 fard with imam, and 4 sunnah ba'dal- Jumu'ah.

Is it permissible to omit 4 sunnah kabla-l jumu'ah? Can it be prayed after the fard namaz as qada'/late sunnah namaz?

**َQuestion:** From the the Sunni Hanafi perspective, can the nafl prayers before Jumu'ah prayers be prayed after Jumu'ah prayers instead?

Comment: Well there are many views on this, try searching other answers on this topic, you may find some good answers.

Comment: Well you ask for a sunni, hanafi perspective: Well only the hanafis do pray a special amount of raka'a sunnah before Jumu'ah! And AFAIK the maximum of sunnah raka'a after the Jumu'ah prayer is 4 raka'a, while i knew that some hanafi pray up to 10 raka'a! So hanafi here differ from other schools and AFAIK they have neither a good evidence for the 4 raka'a before nor the 10 raka'a after the Friday prayer! see also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/is-there-a-sunnah-prayer-before-salat-aljumua-friday-prayer?rq=1